# How to generate event listener function in angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs

How to generate event listener function in angularjs directive?

For something like this:

Directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', () => {
    return {
        scope: {
            myDict: '=',
        },
        templateUrl: 'directives/my-directive',
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- my-directive.html -->

<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in myDict">
    <!-- Will not work -->
    <a onclick="function_written_in_frontend({{key}})">{{value}}</a>
</li>
```

Use it:

```
<my-directive myDict="{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}"></my-directive>
```

What I hope is that it might generate:

```
<li>
    <a onclick="function_written_in_frontend('a')">1</a>
    <a onclick="function_written_in_frontend('b')">2</a>
    <a onclick="function_written_in_frontend('c')">3</a>
</li>
```

But I cannot. And `ng-click` might not be the solution here.

Thx in advance.

---

Update:

If I updated my Directive like this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', () => {
    return {
        scope: {
            myDict: '=',
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.function_written_in_frontend = function(mykey) {
                console.log(mykey);
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'directives/my-directive',
    };
});
```

And it gives me:

```
{{key}}
{{key}}
{{key}}
{{key}}
```

Comment: "But I cannot"? What does that mean? Also, `ng-click` is the preferred way of adding onclick event handlers in AngularJS.

Comment: *"ng-click might not be the solution here"* ... why not? What does `function_written_in_frontend` mean? Everything client side including angular is the front end. Using inline `onclick` is not preferred way to do event handling in native script anyway

Comment: Can I call a function written in another script included like `<script type="text/javascript" src="mytest.js"></script>`?

Comment: If you have to you can, would probably be better to do from inside angular than using onclick though. Why are you needing to do it in first place?

Comment: Because some old code is written in jQuery using posting and animations, and it's quite a lot to do if porting.

Comment: @charlietfl If we can, how?

Comment: if functions in global namespace can access from anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `ng-click` instead of `onclick`

```
<a ng-click="function_written_in_frontend(key)">{{value}}</a>
```